# converting binary string into float

Tags: python

I have an object that I am storing bits in.

```
class Bitset:
    def __init__(self, bitstring):
        self.bitlist = []
        for char in bitstring:
            self.bitlist.append(int(char))

    def flipBit(self, index):
        val = self.bitlist[index]
        val = (val + 1) % 2
        self.bitlist[index] = val
        self.newBitstring()

    def bitstring(self):
        newString = ''
        for val in self.bitlist:
            newString = newString + str(val)
        return newString

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.bitlist)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bitstring()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.bitstring()
```

Is there anyway I can convert the bits into a float? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Convert the bits into a float".  Do you want to do the equivalent of a C typecast (i.e. have the system interpret the sequence of bits as if it were a float)?  Also, if this is a homework problem, you should add the [homework] tag.

Comment: Thank you for understanding. It is essentially a C typecast. This is not a homework problem though. I just have no idea how to do this.

Comment: How do you want to interpret them as a `float`? As a number between 0 and 1? Two's compliment? You need to be more specific? `struct` only works for floats in IEEE 754 binary format.

Comment: I would like to interpret them using the IEEE 754 format. When I try using `struct` to unpack it I am told that the string can only be 4 characters long. Doesn't the standard require 32 bits?

Comment: You are not storing bits. You are storing integers that happen to have the values 0 or 1. Forget this at your peril.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution that works.  as_float32 could be extended to as_float64 by replacing "I" with "L" and "f" with "d".  See the [struct documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) for an explanation.

```
def as_float32(self):
    """
    See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008
    """
    from struct import pack,unpack
    s = self.bitlist
    return unpack("f",pack("I", bits2int(s)))

# Where the bits2int function converts bits to an integer.  
def bits2int(bits):
    # You may want to change ::-1 if depending on which bit is assumed
    # to be most significant. 
    bits = [int(x) for x in bits[::-1]]

    x = 0
    for i in range(len(bits)):
        x += bits[i]*2**i
    return x
```

Comment: I found a few errors when I adapted the code from my spyder window to something that should work in your object.  They should be corrected now.

Answer (score 5):

There are libraries that can do all this for you if you don't want to reinvent the wheel. My [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) library could help:

```
>>> from bitstring import BitArray
>>> a = BitArray(float=0.34, length=32)
>>> a.bin
'00111110101011100001010001111011'
>>> a.float
0.3400000035762787
>>> a.bin = '01001001011101000010010000000000'
>>> a.float
1000000.0
>>> a.bytes = 'helloall'
>>> a.float
7.819486525216155e+194
```

The float interpretation is only allowed when there are either 32 or 64 bits; take a look at the [documentation](http://packages.python.org/bitstring/index.html) for more details.

Comment: Useful library to convert between IEEE754 and binary32 notation

Comment: it adds extra digits in the float representation. The original number is 0.34. How to keep it as 0.34?