# How to convert 32-bit binary to float

Tags: python, binary, floating-point, ieee-754

I want to perform IEEE 754 conversion from 32-bit binary to float in python.

i have tried this

```
import struct

f = int('11000001101011000111101011100001', 2)
print struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('i', f))[0]
```

but this doesn't work for numbers with negative sign bit.

Expected output should be like this:

```
bintofloat(11000001101011000111101011100001)
>>> -21.56
```

Comment: i have tried `def binaryToFloat(value):
    hx = hex(int(value, 2))
    return struct.unpack("d", struct.pack("q", int(hx, 16)))[0]` but this doesnt work properly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395806/converting-binary-string-into-float

Comment: put that in the question please

Comment: @ergonaut Feel free to edit the post and include it, you've got the rep to do it.

Comment: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2015/01/ieee-floats-and-python.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `struct` as follows:

```
import struct

f = int('01000001101011000111101011100001', 2)
print struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('I', f))[0]

f = int('11000001101011000111101011100001', 2)
print struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('I', f))[0]
```

Giving you an output of:

```
21.5599994659
-21.5599994659
```

It all depends on how the integer is represented though.

Comment: Nice.. but that wont work if the sign bit is negative. That means if doesn't work for negative floating point numbers.

Comment: If you pack the integer as unsigned using `I` it will fix the problem. I have updated the answer.