# convert a binary number (consists of the sign, mantissa and exponent ) to decimal number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, binary

I have some 32bits binary numbers. I want to convert them to decimal form. does exist any built-in function or general solution for this task?
The following image shows an example.

[image].

Comment: `np.frombuffer` might work.  Give an example or two.

Comment: You presumably want to convert from the `int` value to a `float` in a custom way (interpreting the bits according to that diagram), and then *display* the float in decimal.

Comment: no according to the above image I have some  32 bits numbers. for example, I  have such a number: "11000011011110001100000000000000" which its conversion is -248.75

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert 32-bit binary to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483846/how-to-convert-32-bit-binary-to-float)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use struct module.

```
import struct
def bin_to_float(binary):
    return struct.unpack('!f',struct.pack('!I', int(binary, 2)))[0]

print(bin_to_float("11000011011110001100000000000000"))
##Output -248.75
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know why I'm getting nan with this :bin_to_float("11111111111101111010111000010100")

Comment: I am getting `nan` when I convert Online also - https://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_float.html

Comment: The exponent here has all `1` bits, and [according to the specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) this is reserved for special values. So a `nan` is not surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Working from:

[What's the correct way to convert bytes to a hex string in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624453/whats-the-correct-way-to-convert-bytes-to-a-hex-string-in-python-3)

```
In [54]: bytes.fromhex('c378c000')                                                                     
Out[54]: b'\xc3x\xc0\x00'
In [55]: np.frombuffer(bytes.fromhex('c378c000'), '>f4')                                               
Out[55]: array([-248.75], dtype=float32)
```

`np.float32` is IEEE 754 format.